# on the impulse to vectorise all the things

Tags: julia, vectorization, broadcasting

I'm coming to julia from years of R and Matlab, where vectorised code was key for performance and has affected my thinking. Now, reading this [wonderful blog post 'more dots'](https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots) by S. Johnson I'm convinced that julia's syntactic loop fusion is a great feature of the language, but it leaves me a bit confused when it comes to porting my previously vectorised code.

*Is it bad / poor form to have some functions vectorised over a few parameters?* – *Should I instead write "scalar" versions of all the routines and call the dot version (or broadcast / map) when I want to iterate over an array?*

For the sake of argument, say I write the following

```
function sphere_vol(r)
    return 4/3*pi*r^3
end
```

and then use it in another function,

```
function density(N, r)
    V = sphere_vol(r)
    return N/V
end
```

and so on (many functions calling each other). My instinct (coming from other languages) is to define most functions as vectorised *whenever convenient*, as in `sphere_vol(r) = 4/3*pi*r.^3` (trivial change). Is there any point to do so, if I can automatically call `sphere_vol.(r::Array)` (or `map(sphere_vol, r::Array)`? For a single-argument function this is not an important decision to make, but for multiple arguments it can change dramatically the implementation: I could define a vectorised version of `density(N, r)` vectorised over `r`, or over `N`, or both (returning a matrix), but it's much less trivial to write this way (needs to call broadcast internally over `sphere_vol.()` and `./`). In R and Matlab I made this choice on a case-by-case basis with this compromise in mind:

1. vectorisation is (was) more convenient and more efficient: I can call `density(N::Vector, r::Vector)` once and get a full array of values.
2. *writing* a vectorised function over several parameters quickly becomes cumbersome and/or unmanageable (2 parameters is usually OK with some tricks); especially when the return values are not scalars.

I do not know how to make the judgment call when implementing a new function in julia.

Would it be correct to say that in julia I'd be better off writing *only* "scalar" versions as above? Or is it the case that some routines will be more efficient if vectorised over some parameters (e.g special functions such as Bessel, which call Fortran routines)? 
I'm guessing there's a subtle balance to find (according to taste/style, also), but with much less impact on performance than with R or Matlab.

Answer (score 4):

That is a good question. I can only provide my personal view on this.

The way I write code in Julia consists of two steps:

1. Write a compact vectorized (or matricial) version of a function:

   - This is usually very quick to do because it matches mathematical derivations on paper
   - It is less error-prone, you will rarely introduce an indexing bug
   - It is also very convenient because, as you pointed out, some built-in functions expect arrays to just forward them to LAPACK, BLAS, FFTW, etc.
2. After I have a working (and tested) implementation, I *sometimes* devectorize it:

   - For instance, if the function is being called multiple times in a loop, and the vectorized version allocates memory inappropriately, there is room to improve performance by not using an array at all, and just looping indices explicitly.

Again, this is just my current take on it, maybe I change mind in the future? At the moment this works pretty well for me because I am at the prototyping stage of my projects.

Going further, we often say Julia addresses the so called two-language problem. You can start naive and build very complex API. Later on, if you didn't fail badly in terms of design, there is always a way to make things fly.

Answer (score 1):

The Julia compiler can inline any function into generated code.

In your example, I would implement the scalar version `sphere_vol(r::Real) = 4/3*pi*r^3` and go ahead and nest the function calls as described: `density(N::Real, r::Real) = N / sphere_vol(r)`.

The compiler would probably pull `sphere_vol` into its compiled implementation of `density`.

The same thing goes for broadcast methods. If you need to compile the density of many spheres:

`function f(x, y, z)
    ... stuff ...
    vols .= sphere_vol.(rs)
    ... more stuff ...
end`

the compiled version will likely have the scalar method baked into the broadcast.

Write the code that is easiest to inspect and maintain. Use type annotations. Julia will take care of the rest.

Comment: interesting, thanks. Does this mean the compiler ends up creating huge executable code because it's inlining multiple versions of the same code? Also, how much of this is guaranteed (I note a few "probably" in your answer)?

Comment: Inlining, or [inline expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) is done by most compilers when it is valuable to do so. The article op refers to discussed exactly such inlining. In the section on the importance of higher-order inlining it discusses how Julia's compiler can make better decisions on when to do so. 
Huge executable code is avoided by the compiler. It only inlines when it is heuristically useful to do so. Inlining is not guaranteed as far as I know. You can view the generated code using `code_native` if you want to know for sure.

Comment: I see, thanks. Regarding `Write the code that is easiest to inspect and maintain.` it sounds reasonable, but coming from different languages I have biased views of what is elegant that may not suit julia's preferred style. I should mention that I've coded this exact same code in R, C++ and Matlab (always with disappointing results for various reasons), so I'm really hoping for some gain in performance this time, which will require that I figure out how to code efficiently in julia (not just getting something that works).

Comment: Right - my that line I meant that if it is easier for your group to read vectorized code, use that, and if it is easier for your group to read non-vectorized code, use that.